# Caching in UrlFetchApp

Tags: google-apps-script, caching, urlfetch

In Google App Script I'm using `UrlFetchApp()` to bring in some code served from an outside host.  I make changes to the code served on that host but these aren't appearing in the code run by script.

My server logs show that the desired is sometimes requested (and served) but it isn't showing up in the script.

I'm using `optAdvancedArgs` in my UrlFetchApp call, passing in `{"headers" : {"Cache-Control": "no-cache"}`

but this isn't helping.

Is there some kind of caching of resources obtained by `UrlFetchApp()`, and if so how can I turn it off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the header Cache-Control to max-age=1 seemed to fix the problem.

This discussion provided some helpful context: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching

Comment: `"headers": {"Authorization": "Bearer HEreTheToken", Cache-Control": "max-age=1"}` seems doing the trick indeed

Answer (score 0):

Set your URL dynamicaly like this:

```
var url = "https://yoururl.com/?" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000);
var responseUrl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
```